# Problem with Select2 and Livewire 3: selected items are not displayed in the dropdown list itself (select) after selection

Tags: laravel-livewire

I recently upgraded to Livewire 3 and encountered an unexpected issue with the integration of Select2. While the Livewire model correctly receives the data, and the data is visible within the DOM, it fails to display within the Select2 dropdown.

```
  <x-form.livewire.select-ajax wire:model="menu_fields1" wire:init="select2" id="menu_fields1"
    placeholder="{{ __('Menu fields') }}" :values="$menu_fields1"       :route="route('fields.ajax.search')"
    :model="App\Models\Access\Field::class" multiple='multiple'>
  </x-form.livewire.select-ajax>
```

This Livewire component integrates Select2 for dynamic dropdown functionality. The Livewire model (menu_fields1) is utilized to manage the selected values.

Livewire Props and Data Initialization:

```
@props(['id', 'route', 'model', 'values' => null, 'placeholder' => ''])

 @php
    $items = [];
    if ($values) {
        $items = $model::search(['codes' => $values])->get();
    }
 @endphp
```

Livewire component props are defined, including id, route, model, values, and placeholder. Additionally, the $items variable is populated based on the provided values.

```
 <div class="select-container">
    <select id="{{ $id }}" {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'text-sm border-0 border-gray-300  shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full']) !!}>
        @if ($items)
            @foreach ($items as $item)
                <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </select>
 </div>
```

The HTML structure for the Select2 container is defined, displaying the dropdown with options fetched from the Livewire model.

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('select2', event => {
            $(function() {
                $("#{{ str_replace('.', '\\\\.', $id) }}").select2({
                    placeholder: '{{ $placeholder }}',
                    allowClear: true,
                    multiple: true,
                    ajax: {
                        url: '{{ $route }}',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 250,
                        data: function(params) {
                            console.log('Search term:', params.term);
                            return {
                                value: params.term
                            };
                        },
                        processResults: function(data) {
                            return {
                                results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        text: item.name,
                                        id: item.id,
                                    };
                                }),
                            };
                        },
                    },
                    minimumInputLength: 3,
                }).on('change', function(e) {
                    var data = $(this).val();
                    @this.set('{{ $id }}', data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

The script initializes Select2, configuring it for dynamic AJAX-based data retrieval. The Livewire model is updated on changes to keep it in sync.

I'm seeking insights into why the data is not being displayed in Select2, even though it's present in the DOM. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!